# bitrix d7 route parameters

Tags: php, routes, bitrix

I am working on project which is based on BITRIX D7 php framework. We have a need to combine several URLs into one by passing the desired part as a parameter in the route. In Laravel it is able to create route like

```
Route::get('page/{param}', function ($param) { // action body});
```

Can I do that with Bitrix D7 framework?

Answer (score 0):

If you can understand Russian this [manuak-link](https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/api_help/main/general/urlrewrite.php) help you

You should config urlrewrite.php in root of project.